Android Compose keyboard adds a large padding
My manifest specifies the setting android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
Why does my content shift by such a greater distance when opening the keyboard and how can I fix it? I want the button to rise slightly so that it can be seen. imePadding() doesn't help at all


@Composable
private fun Content(
    contentPaddings: PaddingValues,
) {

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(contentPaddings)
        .imePadding()
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Red, AppShapes.large)
                .animatePlacement()
            .align(Alignment.Center),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "text",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

            AppEditText(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(144.dp)
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

            AppButton(
                text = stringResource(R.string.next),
                buttonType = AppButtonType.Main,
                onClick = {},
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }
    }



Scaffold(
    content = { contentPaddings ->
        Content(
            contentPaddings = contentPaddings
        )
    }
)




We'd need you code to help

Maybe the contentPaddings is causing an issue

I tried without contentpadding, the situation does not change
